# How to Work with IF statement using SQL queries?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am creating a table query where it have different values in every column but when i try to execute its showing me same values in partime jobs column, I want that to be different elements:

[image]
SQL code for that image is

```
SELECT BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC, Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM) AS ["Full-time Undergraduate Enrollment"], Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM) AS ["Part-time Undergraduate Enrollment"], Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM) AS ["TOTAL Undergraduate Enrollment"], Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM) AS ["TOTAL Graduate Enrollment"], Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM) AS ["TOTAL  Enrollment"]
FROM BANINST1_SZVIRST
GROUP BY BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC, BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE, BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE, BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND
HAVING (((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE) In ("201020","201120","201220","201320","201420","201520","201620")) AND ((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE)="01") AND ((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND)="F"));
```

SQl code for partime job is

```
SELECT BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC, Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM) AS ["Part-time Undergraduate Enrollment"]
FROM BANINST1_SZVIRST
GROUP BY BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC, BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE, BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE, BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND
HAVING (((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE) In ("201020","201120","201220","201320","201420","201520","201620")) AND ((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE)="01") AND ((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND)="P"));
```

It should be configured in single table but with different values:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the same number is because you are calculating both columns the exact same way.

You can type `Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM)` as many times as you want, but it's always going to output the same number.

What you need is some logic to determine with the `SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND` is 'F' versus 'P'. So you'll need to allow both `SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND` into the result set, and then use an `IIF` statement to split it up.

Something like:

```
SELECT BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC,
    Count( iif(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND = "F", 1 ,NULL)) AS ["Full-time Undergraduate Enrollment"],
    Count( iif(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND = "P", 1,NULL)) AS ["Part-time Undergraduate Enrollment"],
    Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM) AS ["TOTAL Undergraduate Enrollment"],
    Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM) AS ["TOTAL Graduate Enrollment"],
    Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_PIDM) AS ["TOTAL  Enrollment"]
FROM BANINST1_SZVIRST
GROUP BY BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC,
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE,
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE,
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND
WHERE (
        (
            (BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE) IN (
                "201020",
                "201120",
                "201220",
                "201320",
                "201420",
                "201520",
                "201620"
                )
            )
        AND ((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE) = "01")

        );
```

I'm not sure how you would distinguis a "Undergraduate" from a "Graduate", but the `IF` statement would look similar there. Also, I changed your `HAVING` over to a `WHERE` since you aren't filtering on aggregated or calculated results.

Comment: HI JNevill, Thank you soomuch for answering my question, I found it useful like using the IFF statement but when i am trying to execute it it is showing syntax error ( Missing operator) in query expression in BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND..for undergaduate level code will be ="01" and for graduate it will be =" 02" thank you..